# Typescript Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript

Although my code works (below), typescript is throwing errors saying "Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'."

As you can see I am grabbing the element via jQuery & the element's ID.

```
$(this.id).click(function () {
  this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

But this causes the following error:

```
`TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`.
```

I am not sure what would be the proper way of handling this ts error.

Would anyone let me know?

Thank you in advance.

more code, since it was requested:

```
`/**
* Class represents a flash message
*/
export class FlashMessage {    
flashMessageParentDivID:string;
iconID:string;
textID:string;
$: JQuery;

/**
 * 
 * @param {string} flashMessageParentDiv - the string of the div's ID.
 */ 
constructor (flashMessageParentDiv: string, $: JQuery) {
    this.flashMessageParentDivID = "#"+flashMessageParentDiv;
    this.iconID = "#flash-message-icon",
    this.textID = "#flash-message-text";
    this.$ = $;
}

/**
 * Displays the passed in message with the appropriate status.
 * @param {string} message - the message we want to flash.
 * @param {string} status: either 'error' or 'success'
 */
showWithMessage = function (message: string, status: string) {
    //@todo: maybe throw an error if status does not equal error or   success.
    this.clearAndCreateFlashMessageInnerds();
    this.$(this.flashMessageParentDivID).removeAttr("class");
    this.$(this.flashMessageParentDivID).addClass(status);

    this.$(this.iconID).removeAttr("class");
    this.$(this.iconID).addClass("k-icon k-i-" + status);

    this.$(this.textID).text(message);
    this.$(this.flashMessageParentDivID).show();   

    this.$(this.flashMessageParentDivID).click(function () {
        (<any>this).style.display = 'none';
    });
};
```

...`

[image: typescript throwing errors]

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the HTMLElement lib.dom.ts has a style property. The error must be something else. Most likely something to do with the way the jquery type definition file is written. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4707

Comment: Thank you @Nae, i copy and pasted the error from the SS.

Comment: in regards to toskv, I am getting my jquery definition file from   `"@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",`

Answer (score 44):

use this in your method

```
(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#yourDomElmentID')).style.display = 'none';
```

[image: test code]

i test your code its compile successfully in my code.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: I tried, but it gives a new error:

When I adjust the code so I have 

`$(this.id).click(function () {
            (<HTMLElement>this).style.display = 'none';
        });`

gives me the following error:

`TS2352: Type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>' cannot be converted to type 'HTMLElement'.
  Property 'kendoBindingTarget' is missing in type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`

Comment: hi @RahulGupta thanks for suggestions.i will definitely memories your suggestion in future.

Comment: hello @Daedalus you can't use in jquery function use it another method <button id='id' (click)='clickme()'>hide dom element</button> clickme(){(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#yourDomElmentID')).style.display = 'none';}

Comment: @Daedalus can you post your .ts file?

Comment: If I am to use the document object, how do I get it into my typescript class? I keep getting an error saying that `TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null`.

I even injected the document from the index.js, like so: `declare var document: Document;`

Answer (score 2):

As Manohar Gavit suggested, I needed to typecast. But, his suggestion did not fix my problem. For some reason my jQuery definition file does not recognize `HTMLElement` as having the `style` property, but as you can see below... the definition file does accept `any` with that property.

```
`$(this.id).click(function () {
    (<any>this).style.display = 'none';
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually to take help from Type Safety of TypeScript, I think best solution is to create Custom Event Type because, we have only few use cases of Event, let me illustrate.

1. event.target.value
2. event.current.target.value
3. event.className
4. event.target.style

   and if any further use cases arises, it can be added to the list. 
   We are creating Custom Event Type because otherwise, we have to deal with unnecessary compartmentalization of Event, HTMLButtonElement, HTMLSpanElement, all these don't serve very big purpose for our front-end code. so I created custom interface as below

```
interface IDom{
  value?:string;
  name?:string;
  className?:string;
  style?:any;
}
interface IEvent{
  target?:IDom,
  currentTarget?:IDom
}

const handleChange = (event:IEvent)=>{console.log(event?.target?.name)}
```

Note that all the properties have been kept **optional** because otherwise we unnecessarily get typescript errors, while defining event listeners if we don't pass some property, which doesn't serve a very great purpose!

Comment: how do i use this though ? can u pls give example?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this error in `forEach` and `NodeListOf<HTMLElement>` saved my life

```
document.querySelectorAll('.my-element').forEach((p: HTMLElement, i:number, arr:NodeListOf<HTMLElement>) => {
 arr[arr.length - i].style.color = 'red';
})
```